# Continuous functions and open covers

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $\{V_{i}\}$ be an open cover of $f(X)$.

Why is it that if $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(V_{i})$ is open?

What does the continuity of $f$ have to do with $f^{-1}(V_{i})$ been open?

Comment: What is $X$? What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: At a purely intuitive level continuity means things that are near stay near when mapped.  An open set means every point will have a near neighborhood entirely within the set, so one's intuitive impression should be the continuity should have quite a lot to do with sets and maps of sets being open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topological definition of continuity is that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}V$ is open in $X$ whenever $V$ is open in $Y,$ where $f^{-1}V=\{p\in X: f(x)\in V\}.$ Continuity is an important and useful concept and has many equivalent def'ns.

Comment: Where did you find this definition of continuity or do you just know it?

Comment: You can prove it with the standard definition of continuous.  If f is cont, then V open => there is e so that d(x,y) < e means y in V.  f cont means there is a d so that d(w,z) < d => d(f(x), f(y))  Let w be in f-1(V) then d(w, z) < d => d(f(w), f(z)) < e => f(z) in V so z in f-1(V) so f-1(V) open.  The other way is similar.

Comment: This is the usual definition of continuity in textbooks on topology,except for some that start with metric topologies.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be any point in $f^{-1}(V_i)$.  So $f(x) \in V_i$.

As $V_i$ is open, for  there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon} \subset V_i$.

As $f$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta$ implies $d(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$ so $f(y) \in B_{\epsilon} \subset V_i$.

Let $B_{\delta}(x)$ be a neighborhood around $x$.  Let $y \in B_{\delta}(x) \implies d(x,y) < \delta \implies d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$

$ \implies f(y) \in V_i \implies y \in f^{-1}(V_i) $

$\implies B_{\delta}(x) \subset f^{-1}(V_i) \implies f^{-1}(V_i)$ is open.